# How to decide between two lewis structures when formal charge is the same

Tags: lewis-structure

I'm trying to draw the lewis structure of POCl3. At first, I drew it like this:

[image: Incorrect]

but after checking on google I saw that the correct structure is actually

[image: Correct]

My question is, are there any rules that allow us to decide between two structures such as these? I know that we want to minimize the formal charge, and if there is any formal charge we want to place it according to the atom's electronegativity (negative charge on most electronegative, positive charge on least electronegative). But in this case, both structures don't have any formal charge.

After looking at both structures, I noticed that in the correct one the electron geometry on the oxygen and the phosphorus seem better. In my incorrect structure, the P is AX3E and the O is AX2E2, while in the correct structure the P is AX4 and the O is AXE2. Hence the P has an atom instead of a lone pair and the O has one less atom around it, therefore there is less repulsion. Also there is a double bond instead of single bond, which releases more energy.

Are the electron repulsion and the double bond really why the second structure is preferred, or is there a different explanation? Are there any common rules to decide between lewis structures when there isn't a difference in the formal charge?

Comment: And if you learn a bit more, you'll find that having a pair of formal charges would be better here...